# EvoPdf: how to get total page count or skip header/footer in last page

Tags: pdf-generation, html-to-pdf, evopdf

I am using EvoPDF for generating html to pdf. And I can skip headers/footers in first page. But I can't find any idea to skip them on last page. If I  would get the pagecount, then I can do that. So, is there any way I can achieve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the BeforeRenderPdfPageEvent event handler you can hide the footer in last page like this:

```
HtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

htmlToPdfConverter.BeforeRenderPdfPageEvent += htmlToPdfConverter_BeforeRenderPdfPageEvent;

void htmlToPdfConverter_BeforeRenderPdfPageEvent(BeforeRenderPdfPageParams eventParams)
{
   PdfPage page = eventParams.Page;
   if (eventParams.PageNumber == eventParams.PageCount)
       page.ShowFooter = false;
}
```